# How can I install an Eclipse Neon package in Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, hana

I don't normally use Eclipse or SAP cloud, but I need to for a project.

I need to install Eclipse Neon for compatibility with a plugin I need to use.  Specifically, I am following the video [SAP HANA Academy - HCP predictive services: Getting Started (Trial Edition)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1mbSPTuN_I&list=PLkzo92owKnVwsI3pbK1VXQnZ4Ne3HDmi6&index=1), and need to use the tools mentioned [here](https://youtu.be/K1mbSPTuN_I?t=1m10s), so I can perform the step described [here](https://youtu.be/K1mbSPTuN_I?t=5m1s) to connect to the database.

Apparently the newest version of Eclipse is "Oxygen".  I cannot find a Neon installer, and the tools required for the video are no longer supported in Oxygen.

How can I solve this problem?  Options I see:

1. Find a new video with updated data for how to do this in Oxygen.
2. Figure out how to get Eclipse Neon installed.
3. Figure out how to install the Neon SAP HANA packages in Oxygen.
4. Something else I haven't thought of, but you smart people know how to do ... !

Any help is greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Which error do you get when you install it in Oxygen? Even though I don't recommend it, older versions of Eclipse can be found here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse

Comment: @howlger Thanks. There's no error when I install Oxygen, but the SAP HANA toolkit (plugin?) just doesn't seem to provide the same menu options; specifically "Add Cloud System" option

Comment: May be a companion plugin is missing.

Comment: so the last version which has this option (add a cloud system) is Neon? Now all the HANA development is made in WebIDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Neon (which still has that option to add a cloud system) from here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Neon/3

And configure eclipse to get the packages that connect to Cloud from here:
https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/neon

as Explained here: https://www.sap.com/developer/how-tos/2016/09/hxe-howto-eclipse.html

Choose the following options in step 2 [image]

Comment: so the last version which has this option (add a cloud system) is Neon? Now all the HANA development is made in WebIDE?

Comment: It depends, Web IDE for some stuff, Business Application Studio (https://community.sap.com/topics/business-application-studio ) for newer stuff. HANA Studio has been officially deprecated for a couple of years but you'll need it for older platforms. I'm personally using anything that allows me to deploy HANA design time artifacts (eg, cloud shell here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/sap-on-google-cloud-hana-hdi-containers-and-ci-cd-pipelines-60cedaddfbc8 )

Comment: I mean building XS applications, Business App Studio is only for cloud model cds apps, AFAIK one cannot develop XS in Business Studio

Comment: XS Classic is also deprecated so, yes, the older versions of HANA Studio are what's left.

Comment: Thanks for info. So this Google Cloud Shell works only for HANA deployed on Google servers or for any remote (on-prem) HANA instance?